# Cryptic clue explanation: “I’m not as active for Vacation times.”

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

Explain why “anagram” is the answer to the clue

> “I’m not as active for Vacation times.”

Comment: What is the source of the clue? Are you sure 'anagram' is the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange the letters of "I'm not as active" to get "Vacation times"